# How to pass username and password in image URL HTML.?

Tags: angular, http, query-string, static-content

How to pass username and password as a variable in image URL HTML and angular 6?

I tried this but I am getting error.

***http://......./folder/img.jpg@httpOptions***

Answer (score 1):

1st you shouldn't. It's insecure to have user and password in query parameters.

2nd you could pass the image file name and any other parameters that are secure as query parameters

If you want more help,  please make your question more specific. Give some code and explanation on why you are trying to do that.

The asset URLs are not in your routing in angular. If you want to secure them, then you need to expose them via a backend service.

You can check the structure here as the @ means nothing in the url
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string